# Assign pjax container dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

In my code, I normally had a static pjax container name and could then use the following in my beforeSubmit event.

```
$.pjax.reload({container:'#pjaxContainerName', timeout:5000, async:false});
```

Now, however, the pjax container name needs to be dynamic and I can't seem to get the proper syntax for the above line.  I retrieve the container name properly but can't seem to pass it along.  Below is my latest attempt

```
var pjaxContainer = $('#pjaxId').val();
$.pjax.reload({container:"#"+pjaxContainer, timeout:5000, async:false});
```

What is the right way to pass pjaxContainer as the container:?

If there's a better approach, I'm all ears.  I just need to reload the pjax container on the current page (there is only 1 of them on this page).

### Update 1

Below are few attempts that I tried that failed

```
var pjaxContainerName = $('#pjaxId').val();
var pjaxContainer = $('#' + pjaxContainerName);
$.pjax.reload({
    // static pjax ids
    // *********************************
    // container: '#projectsListGrid', 
    // dynamic pjax ids
    // *********************************
    // container: "#"+pjaxContainer.attr('id'), //no error, but whole page reloads
    // container: pjaxContainerName, //uncaught exception: the container selector 'projectsListGrid5d2fa662b163c' did not match anything
    // container: "#"+pjaxContainerName, //no error, but whole page reloads
    // container: pjaxContainer, // uncaught exception: expected string value for 'container' option; got object
    // container: function(){ return '#'+pjaxContainerName; }, // uncaught exception: expected string value for 'container' option; got function
    timeout:5000,
    async:false
});
```

### Update 2

So, I switched over to using session variables to transfer my id to my modal _form and it does generate the proper javascript code with the proper pjax id, but the pjax reload reloads the entire page and not just the pjax container. I must be missing a setting in my Pjax::begin? Can anyone shed any light on this whole thing?

I have searched my html code and the ids all match

```
<div id="projectsListGrid5d2fc75ee5395" data-pjax-container="" data-pjax-timeout="9000" data-pjax="">
...
$.pjax.reload({container:'#projectsListGrid5d2fc75ee5395', timeout:9000, async:false});
```

but it still reloading the entire page, what am I missing here?

Below is my Pjax container creation from my index

```
$pjaxContainerName = uniqid('projectsListGrid');
Pjax::begin([
        'id' => $pjaxContainerName,
        'enablePushState' => false,
        // 'enableReplaceState' => false,
        'options' => ['data-pjax' => true],
        'scrollTo' => false,
        'timeout' => 9000,
    ]);
```

Comment: when you say it does not work what exactly is happening ? do you get any errors on console or not?

Comment: you should check for the input `#pjaxId` value you are retrieving for the container, is it correct? and does the container with the same id exist ?

Comment: I put in the comments what happens with each variation I attempted.
Yes, the value retrieved for the pjax id, pjaxContainerName , is correct.  pjaxContainer return the object as well.  The issue isn't retrieving the name or object, it's getting the right syntax to pass it to the function.  Instead of using $.pjax.reload is there any way to use the object, pjaxContainer, and reload?

Comment: show your complete view and the javascript code where you are calling the `$.pjax.reload`, apart from that you dont need to use `'options' => ['data-pjax' => true],`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add a data attribute to the elements that triggers the submit as follows:

```
<?php foreach($boo as $foo): ?>
 <?php Pjax::begin([ 'id' => $foo->id ]); ?>
  <form>
   <input />
   <button type="submit" data-pajax-id="<?php echo $foo->id ?>" > Submit </button>
  </form>
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
<?php enforeach; ?>
```

Then in the javascript, after every submit you check for the data-pajax-id

```
const idAjaxContainer = element.data('pajax-id')
```

And after the submit is done you trigger the reload with:

```
$.pjax.reload({container: '#' + idAjaxContainer})
```